# Check if tweet status exists?

Tags: php, http, twitter

I need a way to check if tweet exists. I have link to tweet like `https://twitter.com/darknille/status/355651101657280512` . I preferably want a fast way to check (without retrieving body of page, just HEAD request), so I tried something like this

```
function if_curl_exists($url)
{   

    $resURL = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($resURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($resURL, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($resURL, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, 'curlHeaderCallback'); 
    curl_setopt($resURL, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); 
    $x = curl_exec ($resURL); 
    //var_dump($x);
    echo $intReturnCode = curl_getinfo($resURL, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
    curl_close ($resURL); 
    if ($intReturnCode != 200 && $intReturnCode != 302 && $intReturnCode != 304) { 
        return false;
    }
    else return true;

}
```

or like this

```
function if_curl_exists_1($url) 
{
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);//head request
    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    $ret = false;

    if ($result !== false) {
        //if request was ok, check response code
        echo $statusCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  

        if ($statusCode == 200) {
            $ret = true;   
        }
    }

    curl_close($curl);
    return $ret;
}
```

but both those return null with `curl_exec()`, there is nothing to check for http status code.

The other way is to use twitter api, like `GET statuses/show/:id` https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/show/%3Aid but there is no special return value if tweet doesn't exist, as said here https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/8802

I need advice whats the fastest way to check, I am doing in php.

Comment: What does the twitter API call return if no tweet matches the `id`?

Comment: Docs says nothing about that, as you can read in links above.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to set the Return Transfer flag

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

If the code returns as 30x status you probably have to add the Follow Location flag as well

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Comment: `$url = 'https://twitter.com/darknille/status/355651101657280512';//false even tweet exists
 //$url = 'http://google.com';//works 200
 //$url = 'http://php.net';//works 200
 if( if_curl_postoji1($url) )
  echo "yes";
 else echo "no";`

Comment: so it works for all sites like google, php.net but not for twitter, like they server is set not to respond on HEAD requests, or some additional http params. I guess that fact that https:// is used doesn't affect things.

Comment: just to say I added your 2 curl options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @get_header. It will return an array in which the first item has the response code:

```
$response = @get_headers($url);
print_r($response[0]);
if($response[0]=='HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found'){
    echo 'Not Found';
}else{
    echo 'Found';
}
```